# what's the word for afterward-smart

Tags: word-meaning

I once came upon a word that means "afterward-smart", e.g., claiming to know something would happen only after it happened. For example, somebody said, "I knew the stock market would collapse, that's *so* obvious", but only say so after the stock market has collapsed, never before.

I know there is such word, but I can't find it any more. What is it?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A good option is **hindsight** though it *may* not directly relate to the person.

> [hindsight (n)](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/hindsight) - perception of the nature of an event after it has happened.

The example clarifies it further.

> *'It's easy for us to say that the war was wrong, but we have the advantage of hindsight.'*

Comment: Reminds me of [*second guess*](http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/american/second-guess).

Comment: yes, thanks. the **hindsight** is in fact the word that I was looking for (not hinting that the others are not more appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

The act of making a "prediction" about the past "after the fact" is called **[retrodiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Retrodiction)**. Closely related (but not identical) terms are: [postdiction](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Postdiction), [hindcast](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hindcast), [vaticinium ex eventu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vaticinium_ex_eventu), and [post hoc, ergo propter hoc](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_hoc_ergo_propter_hoc).

Also, there is a common saying:

> **[It's easy to be wise after the event.](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/It%27s+easy+to+be+smart+after+the+fact)** *(British, American & Australian) also* **It's easy to be smart after the fact.** *(American)*

Comment: Thanks. In Chinese, there is a corresponding saying: "事后诸葛亮"， basically mean exactly as afterward smart.